# Keep from dying

Tags: practical-islam, non-muslim

I am not a Muslim but I do have a question. If a (faux) Muslim decides that a person should die according to the Koran, what can the victim say that will make the Muslim stop and think?

This might be a really stupid, or irreverent, question and I apologize ahead of time if it is.

I'm sorry. I appears that someone edited my question. I believe that a Muslim that understands and follows their belief is just as loving and gentle as the rest of us. That is why I said a faux (fake) Muslim. Someone who claims to be a Muslim but does not act in accordance to the beliefs.

Comment: you are welcome linda ,,can you please elaborate your question.Thanks

Comment: OK - but first, let's pretend that I know nothing about Muslims or Islam - which is pretty much the truth.
But, in the news you hear of people being beheaded by (faux) Muslims according to the Koran. I think this is a question a lot of non-Muslims would like to ask but are afraid because of the American political correctness. I'm not condemning anyone, I hope I am not offending anyone, and my question is purely a transparent question. So, if I am captured as an infidel Christian and someone says that, according to the Koran I have to die, what can I say to make that person stop and think?

Comment: **<comments deleted>**. Comments should primarily be used to ask for more information and suggest improvements. Not discussions. Take it [chat] if you want to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue of Muslim terrorism is complex. When you get down to individuals and their particular motivation, you find everything:
Those who are after money, those who are after power, some sincere but ignorants that are being used as cannon fodder,  or a mix of all of that.

From a geopolitical point of view, it is very difficult to figure out truth from falsehood. The mass media and the Internet transmit videos and images which origin is unknown. Various secret services agencies support these groups in covert operations to use them to serve their interests in the region. A mix of state and non-state actors are involved, each with theif own agenda and constantly changing alliances.

What looks like chaos is but the illusion behind which a big game is being played with absolutely no consideration for the pain and destruction being perpetrated.

None of the regional and super powers can be absolved from this terrible tragedy.  All have their hands soaked in blood in spite of the pretty image they display in the media.

Bottom line: Religion is used and abused to cover up the ugly reality of greed and hatred. May God punish all those responsible for these crimes.

As far as we are concerned,  this is completely outside our circle of influence.  All we can do as Muslims is teach our kids to be good with all people regardless of race or religion.

Comment: =Tarik: I absolutely agree about raising our children to be loving, accepting grown-ups.
I also agree that the 'reasons' are vast and, sometimes, unexpected, as in a 'power' will use someone else’s manic, homicidal state to wreak havoc and kill oppositions.
It is terribly sad and brutally true.

Answer (score 1):

> What can the victim say that will make the Muslim stop and think?

*I testify that there is no God but one God called "The Lord God" or in other words "Allah" (The God), and I also bear witness that a man called Muhammad was a prophet of God.*

If that muslim is not baffled i.e. if he did not understand what you just said, say the same above line in Arabic,

> *ašhadu ʾan] lā ilāha illā l-Lāh wa [ʾašhadu ʾanna] Muḥammadan rasūlu l-Lāh* (Source [Shahada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shahada))

You just asked, what will make him stop and think, then this is what at least makes him stop and think for a while. Later, if he will kill or will not kill will entirely depend on the circumstances.

---

> I believe that a Muslim that understands and follows their belief is just as loving and gentle as the rest of us.

When you yourselves, say so, why not give it a try? Explore, ponder, and think of believing.

---

**EDIT**: You can also remind him with this Ayah from Qur'an,

> *Say, [O Muhammad], to those who have believed that they [should] forgive those who expect not the days of Allah so that He may recompense a people for what they used to earn. - Qur'an [45:14](http://quran.com/45/14)*

This has a higher probability that the killer might completely stop, but doesn't guarantee that because as said already, it depends on various circumstances like if, the person is deemed to receive death penalty by the Islamic law, then no one can help.

Comment: my brother azam ,Islam gives freedom to a person ,no one is supposed to say it forcefully

Comment: Where/how am I forcing? The victim still has the freedom to say or not to say. The comment below the line is a friendly advice, not forcing.

Comment: AZAM: Oh I hope I did not cause discord. 
This sounds like some things to try. When your head's on the chopping block (no pun intended), saying anything is better than saying nothing.
I am just a bit confused about your answer, "Whe you yourselves, say so, why not give it a try? Explore, ponder, and think of believing." Can you elaborate please?

Comment: Assuming these people follow Sharia law they should know that they shall be harshly punished the day of judgment for killing non-combatants regardless of their religion. Even Muslims are being killed by these criminals and I would not count on any recipe to escape death. The best is to keep away from such people.

Comment: There is not much you can a tell a brainwashed, sick and murderous person regardless of religion, or any other affiliation for that matter. That kind of person already had all necessary self-justification for whatever he wants to perpetrate.

Answer (score 1):

You said

> "So, if I am captured as an infidel Christian and someone says that,
>   according to the Koran I have to die"

These extremist are beheading people they capture not because they are Christians, in fact they allow Christians to live in their territory provided they pay the taxes. They kill captured Christians for some other reasons like saying the captured person's country is involved in bombing their region, so they want to revenge the bombing by killing. So just declaring that you converted to Islam (as mentioned by another answer) is not going to work. In fact, one captive (Peter Kassig ) tried this and he was also beheaded.

But, there are cases where some of captives were not beheaded like John Cantlie. I think they will spare the captive if they think he is somehow helpful for them, like for using in their propaganda.

So in short, there is no magic words that can deter the terrorist from killing the captive.

Comment: Good day Ziyad:
Thank you for that thoughtful response. Saying that I would change my religion would not happen and I truly believe that whatever happened God would give me the courage to withstand it.

Comment: Linda, the only good reason to change one's religion is out of conviction. Now, shall one falsely declare he changed his religion if it serves him to survive and escape? I believe there is nothing wrong with this. Deep inside you know who you are and what you believe in. Again, the Quran teaches "no compulsion in religion" and historically Christians and Jews lived peacefully on Muslim lands. The Jewish community of Spain fled to north Africa along with the Muslims during the Reconquista and the following Inquisition.